# How to fix `SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0` on laravel API?

Tags: json, laravel, api

So i have 2 APIs for the relational table. I build the API using Laravel.

Here's the code for the one without the id.

```
public function Berita()
    {
        $berita = Berita::with('Kat_Berita', 'Pengguna')
            ->select(
                'id',
                'judul',
                'kategori_id',
                'isi',
                'gambar',
                'tgl',
                'user_id'
            )->get();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Data berita With kategori & pengguna Loaded Successfully',
            'berita' => $berita
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

The one without the ID works just fine, but with the ID, it says like this
[image]

here's the code for that.

```
public function BeritaById($id)
    {
        $berita = Berita::with('Kat_Berita', 'Pengguna')
            ->select(
                'id',
                'judul',
                'kategori_id',
                'isi',
                'gambar',
                'tgl',
                'user_id'
            )
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->get();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Data berita With kategori & pengguna Loaded Successfully',
            'berita' => $berita
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

How to handle `SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0` for this?

Comment: Can you share both responses like dd($berita) before returning response

Comment: @gguney And after that?

Comment: @gguney here's the link to that https://api.kotabogor.my.id/Relation/Berita

Comment: Can you try to remove isi from select and try again?

Comment: @gguney I've removed it, please check again

Comment: check the response in the network tab to see how it actually looks like

Comment: @gguney Nothing to see on network tab..

Comment: You mean you don't get a response at all? Is the request not sent? Is this route even hit?

Comment: like gguney said, please dd($berita) before the response, take a screenshot of the result and please add it to the question